# No Internet access when I useHotspot while VPN is running

Tags: vpn, hotspot

I am having a Redmi 3S+(rooted) and I access Internet in my Laptop by Hotspot. For atleast a month, I cant access Internet when VPN is connected. But works fine if no VPN is connected.

Comment: We need more information here. What device connects to the VPN? The mobile or the laptop? How do you connect to the VPN? Is it an App? What kind of VPN connection do you use?

Comment: Laptop, Windows 10, Turbo Vpn or Thunder Vpn it doesn't matter